# implementing Stack that accepts any type from command line, multiple failed attempts, Golang

Tags: go

I am implementing a Stack that accpets any type from terminal, but failing
(here I am avoiding top element and other things for reader simplicity)

Case 1: not using terminal for user input

```
type Stack struct {
    elements []interface{}
}

func (s *Stack) Init() {
    s.elements = make([]interface{}, 0)
}
func (s *Stack) Push(i interface{}) {
    s.elements = append(s.elements, i)
}

func main() {
    s := Stack{}
    s.Init()
    s.Push("gi")
    s.Push(2)
    fmt.Println(s.elements) // Output: [gi 2]
}
```

this works as expectd.

Case 2: using terminal for user input, but int input from terminal

```
func main() {
    s := Stack{}
    s.Init()
    var a int
    fmt.Printf("enter element to be pushed: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%v", &a)
    s.Push(a)
    fmt.Println(s.elements) // Output: [2]
}
```

Note: if I entered string as input it is giving, Output: [0]

Case 3: using terminal for user input, but string input from terminal

```
func main() {
    s := Stack{}
    s.Init()
    var a string
    fmt.Printf("enter element to be pushed: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%v", &a)
    s.Push(a)
    fmt.Println(s.elements) // Output: ["gi"]
}
```

Note: if I entered int as input, it is accepting it and giving, Output: [2]
Here I checked the type, 2 is stored as string

*Question 1:* Why int type not accepting string and giving Outut as [0] ?
*Question 2:* Why string type accepting int and giving Output as [2] (as type string) ?
(Yes, I know Go is strictly typed, but string type is accepting int and store it as string)

Case 4: here I want to enter any type from terminal to push into Stack, but failing...

```
func main() {
    s := Stack{}
    s.Init()
    var a interface{}
    fmt.Printf("enter element to be pushed: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%v", &a)
    s.Push(a)
    fmt.Println(s.elements) // Output: [<nil>]
}
```

It is not accepting int or string as the input and showing [] as Output.

Case 5: I tried 'type switch' to get the concrete type and then push it to Stack, but failed...

```
func (s *Stack) Push(i interface{}) {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case int:
        s.elements = append(s.elements, v)

    case string:
        s.elements = append(s.elements, v)
    }
}

func main() {
    s := Stack{}
    s.Init()
    var a interface{}
    fmt.Printf("enter element to be pushed: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%v", &a)
    s.Push(a)
    fmt.Println(s.elements) // Output: []
}
```

For any type of input from terminal, it is giving [] as ouput.

*Question 3:* How to give different types as input to be pushed on to Stack

Comment: Your stack implementation is working correctly. You can verify that by printing the value you are pushing. The problem is with scan. If you scan an int value and the value cannot be converted to int, it returns an error (check the error value returned from scan). You cannot scan to an interface{}, and expect it to make the decision for you about the type of the value entered. You can scan a string, and then decide if it is a number or a string, and push it onto the stack.